# Summoning dropped items (arrows)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/summon Item ~ ~3 ~ {Item:{id:tipped_arrow,Potion:"long_weakness",Count:1}}
```

I need help with this. How do I summon a dropped item that has tipped arrow affects? This does not seem to work.

Comment: I believe that the syntax is off - using `/summon item` creates a new item, which is not what you're after. I think you want to use something along the lines of `/summon @e` instead maybe, then give it the effect?

Comment: @Ben the command works. It summons a dropped item just like I want it to Just the "Potion:"long_weakness" does not apply to the arrow like I wish it too.

Comment: Ohhh, I read that wrong. I was thinking you wanted to summon arrows that had been dropped. Ignore me

Comment: Have you tried just using `Potion:"weakness"`?

Answer (score 5):

Item data that is not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, and `Slot`, must be placed within a single `tag` compound:

```
/summon Item ~ ~3 ~ {Item:{id:tipped_arrow,Count:1,tag:{Potion:"long_weakness"}}}
```